# Let $A$ be an operator, such that $A^{\dagger}A$ is a projector. Show that $AA^{\dagger}$ is also a projector

Tags: linear-algebra, projective-space, projection, projection-matrices

There is a **hint** to this problem which I don't know how to interpret. The **hint** is

$$ \text{Hint: Show that} \quad A | \phi \rangle = 0 \leftrightarrow A^{\dagger}A=0. $$

**Attempted solution**(without using the hint): If $A^{\dagger}A$ is a projector we must have 
$$(A^{\dagger}A)(A^{\dagger}A)= A^{\dagger}A$$
which implies
$$ AA^{\dagger}=I$$
 I could say the identity is a projector and I would be done, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This attempted solution is wrong, as $I$ is not the only solution to $P^2 = P$. The zero operator is a projector, for example. (That equation characterizes projections, by the way.)

Comment: Why does $A^\dagger (A A^\dagger - 1)A = 0$ imply $A A^\dagger -1 = 0$? Clearly $A$ is not invertible.

Answer (score 1):

Since $A^*A$ is a projector, we have $\sigma(A^*A) = \{0,1\}$. Then also $\sigma(AA^*) = \{0,1\}$.

$AA^*$ is self-adjoint and hence diagonalizable. This implies that the minimal polynomial of $AA^*$ splits into linear factors over $\mathbb{C}$. Its possible zeroes are $0$ and $1$ so the only possible candidates are $x, x-1, x(x-1)$.

Hence $x(x-1)$ annihilates $AA^*$ so $(AA^*)^2 =AA^*$. $AA^*$ is also self-adjoint so we conclude it is an orthogonal projector.

---

This assumes that we are dealing with matrices. If these are operators on a Hilbert space, then notice that again $B$ self-adjoint and $\sigma(B) = \{0,1\}$ implies that $B^2 = B$. Indeed, the polynomial $p(x) = x(x-1)$ annihilates $\sigma(B)$ so the spectral mapping theorem implies
$$\{0\} = p(\sigma(B)) = \sigma(p(B)) = \sigma(B^2 - B)$$
Hence $B^2 - B$ is a normal operator with zero spectrum, so it is $0$.

Comment: Sorry, but what is $\sigma$?

Comment: @Slayer147 The spectrum, set of eigenvalues of an operator.

Comment: I am now following what does it mean to a polynomial annihilates $AA^*$

Comment: @Slayer147 $x(x-1)$ annihilates $AA^*$ means $(AA^*)(AA^* - I) = 0$. In general $\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i$ annihilates $B$ if $\sum_{i=0}^n a_iB^i  =0$.

Comment: I am trying to understand your proof: The possibles eigenvalues are 0 and 1, so that the characteristic equation will have factors of $x,x-1, x(x-1)$ this I understand, But I have never heard of minimal polinomial and what it means for a minimal polinomial to annihilate something. Maybe because I dont have a math degree.

Comment: @Slayer147 The minimal polynomial of a matrix is the monic polynomial of minimal degree which annihilates the matrix (I defined it above). The zeroes of the minimal polynomial are precisely the eigenvalues, same as the characteristic polynomial. There is a theorem which states that a matrix is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$ if and only if  its minimal polynomial splits into linear factors over $\mathbb{C}$.